# Image classification Using CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am working on breast cancer classification. I found this online code to train my pre-processed outputs on it. The results was awful but I didn't understand the code, I want to train my own model but I don't how to replace my own code with this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
in_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=(224,224,3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet',classes = 2)
in_model.trainable = False
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x = in_model(inputs)
flat = Flatten()(x)
dense_1 = Dense(4096,activation = 'relu')(flat)
dense_2 = Dense(4096,activation = 'relu')(dense_1)
prediction = Dense(2,activation = 'softmax')(dense_2)
in_pred = Model(inputs = inputs,outputs = prediction)
```

Comment: Do not ask open ended questions, we only accept questions that are answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#This is a Deep Learning model using Keras.
#the CNN model:

```
 in_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=(224,224,3),
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet',classes = 2)
```

#First, to all, you need to creates a CNN DenseNet121 model with pre-trained #ImageNet weights. input_shape specifies the shape of the input images to the model. #include_top=False specifies that we don't want to include the last fully-connected #layer in the model. This is because we want to replace the last layer with our own #layers for our specific task. weights='imagenet' specifies that we want to use pre-#trained weights from the ImageNet dataset. Finally, classes = 2 specifies the #number of output classes for our specific task.

```
in_model.trainable = False
```

#The model freezes the weights of the pre-trained model, so they will not be updated #during training. This is because we only want to train the new layers that we add #to the model.

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
```

## the input layer of the model is defined as  shape=(224,224,3) specifies the shape of #the input images.

```
x = in_model(inputs)
```

#Now is applied the pre-trained model  to the input images to extract features.

```
flat = Flatten()(x)
```

## flattens the output of the pre-trained model into a 1-dimensional array, #so it can be used as input to the fully-connected layers that we will add next.

#Now, in the next two lines add two fully-connected layers with 4096 units each and #ReLU activation functions. These layers are added to learn more complex features #from the flattened output of the pre-trained model.

```
  dense_1 = Dense(4096,activation = 'relu')(flat)
  dense_2 = Dense(4096,activation = 'relu')(dense_1)
```

#The next step involves to adds the output layer of the model. It's a fully-#connected layer with 2 units (one for each output class) and a softmax activation #function. This layer will output the predicted class probabilities for each input #image.

```
prediction = Dense(2,activation = 'softmax')(dense_2)
```

#Finally, you create the final model by defining the input and output layers. #inputs and prediction are the input and output layers that we defined earlier. The #resulting in_pred model is a Keras Model object that can be trained on data for a #specific classification task.

```
 in_pred = Model(inputs = inputs,outputs = prediction)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `preprocess_input`:

> Note: each Keras Application expects a specific kind of input preprocessing. For DenseNet, call tf.keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input on your inputs before passing them to the model.

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x = tf.keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input(inputs)  # HERE
x = in_model(x)
```

You can also try to use the default top-net by setting `include_top=True` or create [the same top net](https://%20%20%20%20if%20include_top:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20=%20layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name=%22avg_pool%22)(x)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20imagenet_utils.validate_activation(classifier_activation,%20weights)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20=%20layers.Dense(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20classes,%20activation=classifier_activation,%20name=%22predictions%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)(x)):

```
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(x)
x = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
```